# IBM worklight:7.1: failure. state: 500, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-cli

I am using mobilefirst 7.1 CLI and have my services running on tomcat. My adapter talks with the services on the servers and gets back the response. I have only desktopbrowser environment in the application (Guessing that should not matter at all).

I am getting this error

> " failure. state: 500, response: The server was unable to process the
>   request from the application. Please try again later."

And followed by :

Client registration failed with error: {"responseHeaders":{"$WSEP":"","Date":"Mon, 07 Dec 2015 17:00:58 GMT","Connection":"Close","Content-Type":"text/html;charset=UTF-8","X-Powered-By":"Servlet/3.0","Transfer-Encoding":"chunked","Content-Language":"en-US"},"status":500,"responseText":"\r\nhttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en-US\" lang=\"en-US\">\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nbody{\r\n    margin:0px;\r\n    padding:0px;\r\n    background-color: #ffffff;\r\n    color:#000;\r\n    font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,Tahoma,sans-serif;\r\n}\r\n#content {\r\n    font-size: 1em;\r\n    margin-left: 1em;\r\n    margin-right: 1em;\r\n    padding: 1em;\r\n}\r\nh4.basichead {\r\n    font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,Tahoma,sans-serif;\r\n}\r\np {\r\n    padding-top: .5em;\r\n}\r\nul {\r\n    line-height: 1.3em;\r\n}\r\na:link { \r\n    color: #c00000 \r\n} \r\na:visited { \r\n    color: #c00000 \r\n}\r\n#page {  \r\n    border: 7px; \r\n    padding: 7px\r\n}\r\n#box {  \r\n    margin: 0;  \r\n}\r\n#title {\r\n    font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,Tahoma,sans-serif;\r\n    font-size:24px;\r\n    font-weight: normal;\r\n    color:#274a71;\r\n    padding-bottom:6px;\r\n}\r\n#error {  \r\n    colory: #c00004;  \r\n    margin-bottom: 10px;\r\n}\r\n#code {  \r\n    font-family: monospace;  \r\n    font-size: 8pt;\r\n}\r\n#stack {  \r\n    margin-left: 30px;\r\n}\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n  \r\n    \r\n\n Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.wink.common.internal.http.Accept.valueOf:139'\n\n\njava.lang.NullPointerException: 
\nat org.apache.wink.common.internal.http.Accept.valueOf(Accept.java:139)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.HttpHeadersImpl.getAcceptHeader(HttpHeadersImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.contexts.HttpHeadersImpl.getAcceptableMediaTypes(HttpHeadersImpl.java:105)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.filterByProduces(ResourceRegistry.java:558)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.filterDispatchMethods(ResourceRegistry.java:482)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry.findMethod(ResourceRegistry.java:359)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:138)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
at [internal classes]
at com.worklight.authorization.server.AuthorizationServerFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationServerFilter.java:85)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at [internal classes]
at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
at [internal classes]
\n\n    \r\n  \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\n","errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.","invocationContext":null}

---

**update**

We have been running with MFPF 7.1 for a month now. This issue with the adapters (there are two of us with the same problem) has only happened over the last couple of days. The current version of Java that we are using is 8.

As well as failing from our browsers (the trace my colleague posted), I have tried testing the adapters using the MF CLI which also fails

```
$ mfp adapter call

Which adapter do you want to use? OrganisationAdapter

Which endpoint do you want to use?  OrganisationAdapter/retrieveOrganisation

Enter the comma-separated parameters: 1

How should the procedure be called? GET
```

Outcome:

```
undefined:1
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/lib/call.js:592:38)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:486:13)
```

Comment: By default MFPF 7.1 is running in session-independent mode (search the IBM Knowledge Center about this). This new mode *does not support* the Desktop Browser environment. Did you make sure to change the server mode to session-*dependent*?

Comment: I have changed the following property in worklight.properties : mfp.session.independent=false which was initially true. I saw a note in the same file which says the following " Note - if the project is configured to work in session dependent mode (mfp.session.independent=false),
#  the storage type of the attribute store must be set to HttpSession. ", so I had to change the following property also:  mfp.attrStore.type=HttpSession. Then I tried. restarting the server and run the application. It did not help. I was still getting the same error in the common resource preview version.

Comment: Please improve your answer by *editing it* instead of using comments.

Comment: I think MFP doesn't support java 8. Anyway, I have the same problem with java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem. Actually both, state 500 and the problem with adapter call. And in my case the problem also suddenly appeared. Literally, on 2nt of December evening everything was OK, next day morning this issue appeared.

My colleague got the same issue and he managed to solve it using the older CLI build. It seems also that Eclipse version works without any problems.

Comment: Can you please tell the version of CLI that you used to get is solved. Also will be helpful if you can share the link to download

Comment: which version are you using? it's still broken on 7.1.0.00.20151214-1903

Comment: I am now using MobileFirst CLI: 7.1.0.00.20150913-2352. Its working fine.