# Unexpected token < when invoking an adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I've just started the tutorial courses of IBM Mobile First Platform (https://mfp.help/canteenpos-hybrid-1-day-pot/) but I'm having a problem with my adapter.

After pushing my adapter to my local MFP server, I tried to invoke my adapter using the "mfp invoke" command. However I keep getting this error message:

```
C:\workspaces\canteen\canteenPOSwl>mfp invoke
Invoking 'getMenu', the only procedure available for 'canteenAdapter' adapter.
? Enter the comma-separated parameters:

undefined:1
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at Object.parse (native)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\ibm\MobileFirst-CLI\mobilefirst-cli\lib\invoke.js:301:38)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:944:16
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:486:13)
```

The lab where I cannot invoke the adapter: https://mfp.help/2015/10/04/lab-7-3/

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue related to latest CLI version. Please provide details about the version you are using.

I also suggest to follow this topic [Issue accessing MobileFirst adapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158550/issue-accessing-mobilefirst-adapters)

and downgrade to previous release.